# Canvas won't draw rectangle after for loop in function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a news ticker that renders text in little square "pixels". I say "pixels" because they look like pixels but the actual squares being displayed are bigger than just 1px.

So far I can get all the letters rendered from an object that I built which contains the pixel coordinates for each rectangle. Code can be seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9u3ez6gu/2/

The letters render correctly, but after my for loop (see code sample below) I'm trying to create a lime colored space between each letter. This lime space never gets rendered no matter what I do. Here is the for loop and the code I'm using to render the space. Does anyone know why canvas will not let me draw the lime colored rectangle?

```
for (i = 0; i <= inv[letter].length; i++) {
    var x = inv[letter][i][1] * full;
    var y = inv[letter][i][0] * full;
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x, y, unit, unit);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}// End for loop

//Add a gap between letters
var gapx = full * 5;
context.beginPath();
context.rect(gapx, 0, full, full);
context.fillStyle = 'lime';
context.closePath();
context.fill();
}// End function
```

Comment: Have you tried using `"#00FF00"` instead of `"lime"`?

Comment: Oh yes, I failed to specify that I have tried different color codes but to no avail. The results were the same as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop goes one iteration too far:

```
for (i = 0; i <= inv[letter].length; i++) {
```

Should be `<`, not `<=`.  **Keep your developer console open!**

Also, `i` should be declared with `var`, either at the top of the function or in the `for` loop header itself. In this case it (probably) doesn't matter, but it's good to get in the habit. If you don't declare the variable, it'll be global. If another of your functions *also* fails to declare another `i`, they'll be the same thing, and weird bugs can result.

If you put

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of your `<script>` blocks or the very top of each function, the parser (in modern browsers) will flag assignments to implicit global variables as errors.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Could you please explain for my own understanding, why is it important to declare i with var first?

Comment: @DigitalBrent ok I'll extend the answer.